# What does the "S" power-up do in Tony Hawk's Pro Skater for Game Boy Color?

Tags: tony-hawks-pro-skater-gbc

In *Tony Hawk's Pro Skater* for the Game Boy Color, (yes it exists), there are collectable power-ups with an "S" symbol on them. They appear on the ground in 'Tournament Mode' and '1on1 Vs CPU Mode'.

What does the "S" power-up do? How do I use it?

[image: S powerup in Tony Hawk's Pro Skater for GBC]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only appears in the downhill racing modes and allows you to speed up. Just double press **Up** and you will speed up until you hit max speed.